# Computing Values for Groups of Data Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big Excel file with listed participants and dates. I want to calculate, for each date, how many days it is from the first (start) date for each participant. Each start date is different, and each participant has a different number of entries. I know what formula I need to do the calculation, but I'm stumped on how I can recursively calculate for each participant without doing it manually! Example for what I have and want:

```
Participant Date    Days from Start
ca002   01/01/1983  0
ca002   10/05/1984  495
ca002   01/01/1986  1096
ca002   01/01/1986  1096
ca002   29/12/1999  6206
ca002   21/03/2001  6654
ca002   31/12/2004  8035
ca004   01/01/1967  0
ca004   01/01/1972  1826
ca004   01/01/1989  8036
ca004   01/01/2006  14245
ca004   01/01/2006  14245
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the `A` and `B` columns, the first row is a header row, and your dates for each participant are in chronological order, you can type this formula into cell `C2` and drag down as far as necessary:

```
= B2-INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH(A2,A$2:A2,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the latest date, you could use a PivotTable to get the first and last dates, and then just subtract one from the other:

[image]